# Reduce opacity of existing image

Tags: preview, graphics, image-editing, macos

Can Apple's Preview app be used to reduce the opacity of an existing image?

I might be asking this wrong. To be clear, I've Googled it extensively but Google seems to think what I want is to remove a solid background from around my image, for example making a the black background/backdrop transparent in an image that's of a car. However, my background is already transparent and what I want is for the car to be at about 90% Opacity.

Comment: Which car? We can't see your picture.

Comment: The transparent one.

Answer (score 14):

`Preview` can't do this.

`ImageMagick` can, and nearly anything you can imagine.

You can easily install it with `MacPorts` (see [MacPorts Home](https://www.macports.org/)):

```
port install imagemagick
```

Let's say your original image is `porsche-911.png`:
[image: Porsche 911]

Enter in `Terminal` the following command:

```
convert porsche-911.png -alpha set -channel A -evaluate set 50% porsche-911-50%.png
```

which will compute from your original input `porsche-911.png` the output
`porsche-911-50%.png`:

[image: Porsche 911 50% transparent]

If you want to learn more about this great free tool, read:

[ImageMagick home](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Comment: That distorts the entire image, and if the background was already transparent(my case and the autor too), the background turn to a back semi opaque color.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to download anything additional, you can do it with Pages (which should come preinstalled on mac).

Here are some quick easy steps:

- Open Pages
- Create a new document (blank template)
- Drag your image in and select it
- On the right panel, the "Style" tab should be open

[image]

- Drag opacity to desired value
- Copy image from Pages (right click > copy, or `cmd + c`)
- open preview a create new from clipboard (file> New from clipboard, or `cmd + n`)
- Enjoy

Result (Before/After):
[image: Result]

Comment: In the future, don’t repost [the same answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/462095/119271) to what is ostensibly the same question.  Flag as a duplicate so it can go into the Review queue for moderation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the background of an image transparent (to some degree) while keeping a foreground object at a different level of transparency, then you're not going to do that on the command line.

You'll need to use a graphics editor - Photoshop, GIMP, Affinity Photo, etc, to create a mask around the object, so that you can then apply the transparency only to the unmasked area. (Or possibly the other way round.)