# Adjust the opacity/transparency of an image on macOS

Tags: macos, graphics, image-editing

I thought I'd be able to do this with the built-in Preview app, but I can't find a way to do that.

I have an image I'd like to reduce the opacity to 50%.

Can anyone advise if there's a way to do this with built-in applications that come with macOS or if this needs GIMP or another image editing tool? I'd rather not install GIMP (if I can avoid it) just for this.

Comment: What is the end use of the image  - for instance if it's going on a webpage you can use CSS to adjust the opacity?

Comment: @MrR Yes, it's going on a webpage however I have limited control as it is set using a Wordpress plugin. I'd like to set the opacity on the background image but not the entire container.

Comment: Perhaps [wordpress wiki on featured image transparency](https://wordpress.com/forums/topic/setting-featured-image-transparency/) can help? (sorry this seems like it might help but wordpress is not my jam).

Comment: See this answer to a very similar question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/251184/22003

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone advise if there's a way to do this with built-in applications that come with MacOS or if this needs GIMP or another image editing tool? I'd rather not install GIMP (if I can avoid it) just for this.

There's nothing built-in to do this and as you've found, the good GUI tools are massive for this kind of work.  Fortunately, there is a much more efficient tool CLI utility called [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).

It's a much [more efficient alternative (smaller and faster) to the popular ImageMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/benchmarks.html).  It's available via [direct download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/), [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/GraphicsMagick/) and [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/graphicsmagick).  It's cross platform: macOS, Windows, FreeBSD, and Linux.  I mainly use it on macOS and FreeBSD and every GM script I write is portable across both operating systems.

#### The command to change the opacity is<sup>1</sup>:

```
gm convert Apple.png -matte -operator Opacity Negate 0 \
-operator Opacity Multiply 0.5 -operator Opacity Negate 0 \
Apple-out.png
```

#### Results:

[image: Original Apple] [image: 50% Opacity Apple]

#### Order of Operations

The operation: `-operator Opacity Negate 0 -operator Opacity Multiply 0.5 -operator Opacity Negate 0` is the secret sause here.

1. It negates (like a [film negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_(photography))) the Opacity channel so it can be manipulated
2. It then multiplies the Opacity channel by .5 or 50%
3. Finally, it negates the negative so it's back to the original

The `-matte` is included should the Opacity channel not exist.

---

<sup>1</sup> Information was sourced from discussion post by [Bob Friesenhahn, GraphicsMagick maintainer](https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/discussion/250738/thread/4ebaf0ed/).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to download anything additional, you can do it with Pages (which should come preinstalled on mac).

Here are some quick easy steps:

- Open Pages
- Create a new document (blank template)
- Drag your image in and select it
- On the right panel, the "Style" tab should be open

[image]

- Drag opacity to desired value
- Copy image from Pages (right click > copy, or `cmd + c`)
- open preview and create new from clipboard (file> New from clipboard, or `cmd + n`)
- Enjoy

Result (Before/After):
[image: Result]

Comment: Pages is free, but I don’t believe it’s comes preinstalled with macOS - it’s a separate download and must be installed.

Comment: @Allan I'm pretty sure it does come preinstalled. See here https://support.apple.com/guide/macbook-pro/included-apps-apd83cde9f0c/mac

Comment: [This page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/view-built-in-apps-mchl110b00b7/mac) indicates it’s possible that it doesn’t always come pre-installed and must be downloaded.   That was my experience

Comment: You’re both correct IMO. Pages is not part of the OS and it is typically preinstalled with a new Mac from Apple build process to most (but not all) computers globally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're going to need a graphic image editor, be it GIMP, or Pixelmator, or Affinity Photo, or Adobe Photoshop, or other.

Having some sort of program of this type is bound to come in useful again. Preview has its uses, but it's not a general-purpose image editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Office you can easily do this using Microsoft Word. Open a new document, insert the picture into the document, select the picture, then open the "Picture Format" tab. One of the tools in the toolbar is "Transparency".
[image]
Adjust the transparency, then right click on the image and select "Save as Picture". You can then save the image to a new file with the transparency you have selected.

Answer (score -2):

You don't strictly have to install something, there are always online tools like https://www.online-image-editor.com/.

I would definitely say that you have many options (there is even a backwards way with word like described here https://www.maketecheasier.com/make-transparent-images-osx/ -- WHY??? oh well...

it's a user's world now, enjoy.

Comment: Link only answer